# Invalid Thread ID Error When Replying to Facebook from Salesforce

Tags: api, integration, facebook, social, radian6

We have enabled Social Customer Service in a sandbox. It runs perfectly well for me however one of the testers gets the below error when he tries to reply to a facebook message/post from the Salesforce quick action.

> 504 400
>   Received Facebook error response of type OAuthException:
>   Invalid reply thread id (code 504, subcode 1545025)

I can reproduce the error using both the starter pack and radian6. I have checked the facebook account settings and they look fine. I'm not able to find a great deal of info in the facebook documentation about what the error really means.